# Conflict between Corolla and Panels?

Tags: panels

Wanting to use a mobile savvy html5 theme, I currently chose Adaptive Themes "Corolla", however I have noticed over the past 3-4 days that when I now attempt to add any content to Panel, the Panel interface just hangs and shows the blue 'timer' graphic and goes no where even after 10 minutes. If I revert back to say Bartik and or standard theme it works as expected. Since I'm 'upskilling' with a view to future employment, I would like to know what causes such issues now of for future reference, what is is hanging on for?

Of course, cosmetically Corolla can be changed for a custom HTML5 theme, but an answer would be helpful. I'm running a webdev Ubuntu LAMP stack on a home webdev box using pure apache so no wamp/xammp etc. The webdev box emulates a live production server for future commercial projects.

The module versions are:

cTools: 7.X.1.0 alpha#1 (doesn't matter if it is later).
Panels: 7.x.3.0 Alpha#2
Views: 7.x.3.0 alpha#1

I have tried a number of the above versions and I have multiple D7 projects on my LAMP box, and it makes no difference so I have concluded it is Corolla, even with the latest strain. I have no desire to go down to Drupal v6.
Thank you.

Paul B.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Pixture Reloaded, another Adaptivetheme and I use Panels for nearly everything on my site and have experienced no such problems.

I have used both the 2.x and 3.x series with no incidents.

I doubt your problem is Corolla; from your post, it is clear you are still running alpha versions of Panels and Views.  These modules have had stable and security releases for D7-- Views is now version 3.3.  You really need to keep your modules up-to-date when there are security releases

Update all your modules to the latest versions (or at least Ctools, Views, and Panels), run `update.php`, and then do this:

1. Enable Corolla.
2. Clear the cache twice.
3. Go to the Corolla theme settings page.
4. Click save.  (It doesn't matter if you make any changes.)
5. Clear the cache twice again.

This will ensure that all the files that are automatically generated by Corolla have been rebuilt properly and should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I shall take your advice well. One project currently is on a D7.0 stack whilst others are on D7.8, they still service the same issues. Rightly so, they do need all updates and it is nice to hear it is not merely my own Drupal. I shall remove the Alphas (The caches were cleared often), however for fear of breaking my vast work, I hadn't updated via the update.php and feedback any known issues that arise.

Comment: Well, the longer you wait to update, the more likely you are to run into errors.  It's very dangerous to keep building on alphas when there have been betas and release candidates and then stable releases.  Also, just fyi, Jeff Burnz, the creator/developer of Adaptivetheme, is one of the leading Panels themers (he released one of the only Panels Everywhere themes for D6 and his new 3.x Adaptivetheme specifically adds responsive design to Panels).  Adaptivetheme has far tighter integration with Panels than most other themes and is very unlikely to cause errors.